# map static IP of a google cloud vm instance to docker container IP.

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, drupal-8

I have created ubuntu vm in google cloud with static IP A.B.C.D. I want to host drupal site (PHP CMS) in a docker. map static IP of a google cloud vm instance A.B.C.D to site hosted in docker.

I have followed https://circleci.com/blog/continuous-drupal-p1-maintaining-with-docker-git-composer/  to setup drupal site in docker.

basically using docker-compose I have created containers for mariadb and Drupal:latest and installed the site.

I want my ubuntu vm to be clean, I haven't installed any apache/nginx server in host machine.

I want to map static IP of a google cloud vm instance to docker container IP so that In browser If I access http://A.B.C.D my site should load.

Do I need to fix this in host machine, google cloud vm setting or else in docker containers is what I am getting confused.

Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is a misunderstanding here, you do not map the computer IP address to a docker container, you map a port.

If your container is running inside an instance it will automatically have the same ip address, what you need to do is to give map the port 80 of your instance to the port 80 of the container.

If you want to have https, you should also map port 443.

You will find more information about it here: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

You can use something like that to make your container be linked to port 80 and 443:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 ...
```